# Is it considered unethical to apply for a internship using an ID card that was just to maintain student status

Tags: internship, ethics, education

I am a college dropout student who was enrolled for a under graduate course last year but later dropped out. Now, I am studying myself full time using books and online videos. I am also planning to keep self studying this year too.

But, my identity card for session 2013-14 is going to expire soon. Since, we have to prove student status by providing valid identity card for perks like internship and many other things, I am planning to enrolled for a cheaper distance education program so as to get a ID card for 2014-15.

Will this be considered unethical by employers when they came to know that I am enrolled just to maintain student status? Are there some problems with it?

Note: I am studying full time like a normal student but the difference is just that I am self educated and not depend upon exams, classes,...

Comment: Is there a reason why you feel you must disclose anything and everything that goes on in your life? Hell, I didn't even want to know what you were doing with your student ID :)

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan There are two problems. What if they ask me questions like when are your exams. And what if they did background check and found I have not attended a single class or exam.

Comment: we have students - first in their family to attend college, married with children - in NYC who take six years instead of the usual four to graduate. If I were to interview them, the fact that they were not registered for a particular semester would not weigh heavily on my mind. I myself was an evening student in NYU Stern's MBA program - it took me 5 1/2 years to graduate, partially because the firm was so busy at times that I simply would have made a hash of my courses if I had registered for that semester. Nobody questioned my status as a student during the time I didn't show up :)

Comment: Hey dropout and welcome to [workplace.se]. Unfortunately there is no way for us to know what an employer will/won't consider unethical, though if you're asking, clearly you think it has potential to be seen as unethical. Whether or not you want to take that risk is something you need to decide for yourself. If you [edit] your question to meet the guidelines in the [help], it will be automatically reviewed for reopening. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5):

If you are applying to internships that have restrictions on the types of students who may apply (such as full-time enrolled students in a degree program), then it's unethical to pass yourself off as a full-time enrolled student in a degree program if you are not.

However, if the internships just require that you are a student of any type, and you are indeed a student of some type, then there isn't an issue.

As a company digs deeper into the background of the candidates applying for internships, they'll discover (through looking at transcripts and talking to references) if the student applications they are receiving are the "right" types that match their needs.  You very well may *not* be it, but that's an issue independent of your student ID card (which you can only get, I imagine, if you are a paying tuition and therefore are a student *of some kind*).

Answer (score 0):

If you are enrolled, then the ID card is not fraudulent.  There is no problem.  Why would you tell them otherwise?

Please reconsider dropping out, though.  The world is a tough place for someone without an accredited degree, these days.